# Javascript doPostBack in jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an existing js function that is fired as a click event on all 'a' elements...

```
$(document).ready(function hideRanges() {
$('a').click(function (event) {
    $('.ranges, #UpdatePanel').hide();       
});
```

});

When an 'a' tag is clicked, 2 div classes are hidden. It works.

I also need this same click event to unbind a SqlDataSource from a GridView in asp.net. Here is the unbind code behind...

```
        protected void unBind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowCount = GridView2.Rows.Count;

        if (rowCount > 0)

        {
            GridView2.DataSource = null;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            RowCount.Text = GridView2.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }

    }
```

It also works. I have hidden this button, though, and need it to fire with the js click event above.

I have tried things such as...

```
$(document).ready(function hideRanges() {
$('a').click(function (event) {
    $('.ranges, #UpdatePanel').hide();
    javascript: __doPostBack('<%= unBindGrid.UniqueID%>', '');
});
```

});

But it does not seem to work properly.

Any advice much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "does not seem to work properly" could mean so many things... Do you get script errors in the browser debug console ? Does your server-side handler actually get called ?

Comment: Hello, thanks...I will check first thing in the morning. No browser errors at runtime, I will update as soon as I can. Thanks again.

Comment: any chance to convince you to **STOP** developing in classic ASP.NET?

Comment: @ymz I suppose there's a chance. Fire away...

Comment: if you are working with C# - Web Api Technology is WAY better + it enable you to enjoy your js skills... follow [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and observer how easy it is compared to classic ASP.NET

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link. I will follow it and see about going that route with my next project. For now, I am building an intranet, data-centric application with 'classic'. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by routing to the ID of the asp:button...

```
$(document).ready(function hideRanges() {
$('a').click(function (event) {
    $('.ranges, #UpdatePanel').hide();
    $("input[id$='unBindGrid'").click();
});
```

});

Thank you!